# AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION

Tags: java, android

> ```
> Gradle sync : No error
> Rebuild Project : No error
> After hitting RUN >> Installing app through ADB
> but unable to launch application. Forced stopped
> ```

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.bookcircuit"
        minSdkVersion 22
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
        manifestPlaceholders = [onesignal_app_id               : "5c3d7b9b-1874-463f-8081-1c3439ccb3ea",
                                onesignal_google_project_number: "REMOTE"]
        multiDexEnabled true
        compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
            targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        }
```

```html
Logcat: 
    2019-05-26 01:29:47.773 29431-29431/com.example.bookcircuit E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.bookcircuit, PID: 29431
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.bookcircuit/com.example.bookcircuit.SplashActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class androidx.constraintlayout.ConstraintLayout
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2928)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3063)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1823)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:198)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6729)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class androidx.constraintlayout.ConstraintLayout
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class androidx.constraintlayout.ConstraintLayout
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "androidx.constraintlayout.ConstraintLayout" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.bookcircuit-UeVp2v3GMHxcnEsLL2108Q==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.bookcircuit-UeVp2v3GMHxcnEsLL2108Q==/lib/arm64, /system/lib64]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:134)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:606)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:790)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:431)
        at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2771)
        at com.example.bookcircuit.SplashActivity.onCreate(SplashActivity.java:25)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7136)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7127)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1272)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2908)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3063)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1823)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:198)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6729)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)


AndroidManifest.xml :
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.bookcircuit">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        tools:node="replace"
        android:name=".init.CustomApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/logo"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/logo"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning">

        <meta-data
            android:name="AA_DB_NAME"
            android:value="MyDatabase.db" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="AA_DB_VERSION"
            android:value="5" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="AA_MODELS"
            android:value="com.example.bookcircuit.db.Notification" />
        <!--
        Add the following to your AndroidManifest.xml to prevent the launching of your main Activity
        if you are calling startActivity above.
        -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.onesignal.NotificationOpened.DEFAULT"
            android:value="DISABLE" />


        <activity android:name=".SplashActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
        android:name=".Register"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:theme="@style/WhiteTheme" />
        <activity
            android:name=".LoginActivity"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />
        <activity
            android:name=".HelpCenter"
            android:theme="@style/WhiteTheme" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Profile"
            android:theme="@style/WhiteTheme" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Cart"
            android:theme="@style/WhiteTheme" />
        <activity
            android:name=".UpdateData"
            android:theme="@style/WhiteTheme"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ForgotPassword"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />
        <activity
            android:name=".NotificationActivity"
            android:theme="@style/WhiteTheme" />
        <activity
            android:name=".prodcutscategory.Cards"
            android:theme="@style/WhiteTheme" />
        <activity
            android:name=".IndividualProduct"
            android:theme="@style/WhiteTheme" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Wishlist"
            android:theme="@style/WhiteTheme" />
        <activity
            android:name=".OrderDetails"
            android:theme="@style/WhiteTheme" />
        <activity
            android:name=".OrderPlaced"
            android:theme="@style/WhiteTheme" />
        <activity
            android:name=".prodcutscategory.Tshirts"
            android:theme="@style/WhiteTheme" />
        <activity
            android:name=".prodcutscategory.Bags"
            android:theme="@style/WhiteTheme" />
        <activity
            android:name=".prodcutscategory.Calendars"
            android:theme="@style/WhiteTheme" />
        <activity
            android:name=".prodcutscategory.Keychains"
            android:theme="@style/WhiteTheme" />
        <activity
            android:name=".prodcutscategory.Stationary"
            android:theme="@style/WhiteTheme" />
        <activity android:name=".WelcomeActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"/>
    </application>



MainActivity :
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private SliderLayout sliderShow;
    private Drawer result;
    private CrossfadeDrawerLayout crossfadeDrawerLayout = null;


    //to get user session data
    private UserSession session;
    private HashMap<String, String> user;
    private String name, email, photo, mobile;
    private String  first_time;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Typeface typeface = ResourcesCompat.getFont(this, R.font.blacklist);
        TextView appname = findViewById(R.id.appname);
        appname.setTypeface(typeface);

        //check Internet Connection
        new CheckInternetConnection(this).checkConnection();

        //retrieve session values and display on listviews
        getValues();

        //Navigation Drawer with toolbar
        inflateNavDrawer();

        //ImageSLider
        inflateImageSlider();

        if (session.getFirstTime()) {
            //tap target view
            tapview();
            session.setFirstTime(false);
    }
}
    private void tapview() {

        new TapTargetSequence(this)
                .targets(
                        TapTarget.forView(findViewById(R.id.notifintro), "Notifications", "Latest offers will be available here !")
                                .targetCircleColor(R.color.colorAccent)
                                .titleTextColor(R.color.colorAccent)
                                .titleTextSize(25)
                                .descriptionTextSize(15)
                                .descriptionTextColor(R.color.accent)
                                .drawShadow(true)                   // Whether to draw a drop shadow or not
                                .cancelable(false)                  // Whether tapping outside the outer circle dismisses the view
                                .tintTarget(true)
                                .transparentTarget(true)
                                .outerCircleColor(R.color.first),
                        TapTarget.forView(findViewById(R.id.view_profile), "Profile", "You can view and edit your profile here !")
                                .targetCircleColor(R.color.colorAccent)
                                .titleTextColor(R.color.colorAccent)
                                .titleTextSize(25)
                                .descriptionTextSize(15)
                                .descriptionTextColor(R.color.accent)
                                .drawShadow(true)                   // Whether to draw a drop shadow or not
                                .cancelable(false)                  // Whether tapping outside the outer circle dismisses the view
                                .tintTarget(true)
                                .transparentTarget(true)
                                .outerCircleColor(R.color.third),
                        TapTarget.forView(findViewById(R.id.cart), "Your Cart", "Here is Shortcut to your cart !")
                                .targetCircleColor(R.color.colorAccent)
                                .titleTextColor(R.color.colorAccent)
                                .titleTextSize(25)
                                .descriptionTextSize(15)
                                .descriptionTextColor(R.color.accent)
                                .drawShadow(true)
                                .cancelable(false)// Whether tapping outside the outer circle dismisses the view
                                .tintTarget(true)
                                .transparentTarget(true)
                                .outerCircleColor(R.color.second),
                        TapTarget.forView(findViewById(R.id.visitingcards), "Categories", "Product Categories have been listed here !")
                                .targetCircleColor(R.color.colorAccent)
                                .titleTextColor(R.color.colorAccent)
                                .titleTextSize(25)
                                .descriptionTextSize(15)
                                .descriptionTextColor(R.color.accent)
                                .drawShadow(true)
                                .cancelable(false)// Whether tapping outside the outer circle dismisses the view
                                .tintTarget(true)
                                .transparentTarget(true)
                                .outerCircleColor(R.color.fourth))
                .listener(new TapTargetSequence.Listener() {
                    // This listener will tell us when interesting(tm) events happen in regards
                    // to the sequence
                    @Override
                    public void onSequenceFinish() {
                        session.setFirstTime(false);
                        Toasty.success(MainActivity.this, " You are ready to go !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onSequenceStep(TapTarget lastTarget, boolean targetClicked) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onSequenceCanceled(TapTarget lastTarget) {
                        // Boo
                    }
                }).start();

    }


    private void getValues() {

        //create new session object by passing application context
        session = new UserSession(getApplicationContext());

        //validating session
        session.isLoggedIn();

        //get User details if logged in
        user = session.getUserDetails();

        name = user.get(UserSession.KEY_NAME);
        email = user.get(UserSession.KEY_EMAIL);
        mobile = user.get(UserSession.KEY_MOBiLE);
        photo = user.get(UserSession.KEY_PHOTO);
    }


    private void inflateImageSlider() {

        // Using Image Slider -----------------------------------------------------------------------
        sliderShow = findViewById(R.id.slider);

        //populating Image slider
        ArrayList<String> sliderImages = new ArrayList<>();
        sliderImages.add("https://www.printstop.co.in/images/flashgallary/large/Business_stationery_home_banner.jpg");
        sliderImages.add("https://www.printstop.co.in/images/flashgallary/large/calendar-diaries-home-banner.jpg");
        sliderImages.add("https://www.printstop.co.in/images/flashgallary/large/calendar-diaries-banner.jpg");
        sliderImages.add("https://www.printstop.co.in/images/flashgallary/large/free-visiting-cards-home-banner.JPG");

        for (String s : sliderImages) {
            DefaultSliderView sliderView = new DefaultSliderView(this);
            sliderView.image(s);
            sliderShow.addSlider(sliderView);
        }

        sliderShow.setPresetIndicator(SliderLayout.PresetIndicators.Right_Bottom);

    }

    private void inflateNavDrawer() {

        //set Custom toolbar to activity -----------------------------------------------------------
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        // Create the AccountHeader ----------------------------------------------------------------

        //Profile Making
        IProfile profile = new ProfileDrawerItem()
                .withName(name)
                .withEmail(email)
                .withIcon(photo);

        AccountHeader headerResult = new AccountHeaderBuilder()
                .withActivity(this)
                .withHeaderBackground(R.drawable.gradient_background)
                .addProfiles(profile)
                .withCompactStyle(true)
                .build();

        //Adding nav drawer items ------------------------------------------------------------------
        PrimaryDrawerItem item1 = new PrimaryDrawerItem().withIdentifier(1).withName(R.string.home).withIcon(R.drawable.home);
        PrimaryDrawerItem item2 = new PrimaryDrawerItem().withIdentifier(2).withName(R.string.myprofile).withIcon(R.drawable.profile);
        PrimaryDrawerItem item3 = new PrimaryDrawerItem().withIdentifier(3).withName(R.string.wishlist).withIcon(R.drawable.wishlist);
        PrimaryDrawerItem item4 = new PrimaryDrawerItem().withIdentifier(4).withName(R.string.cart).withIcon(R.drawable.cart);
        PrimaryDrawerItem item5 = new PrimaryDrawerItem().withIdentifier(5).withName(R.string.logout).withIcon(R.drawable.logout);

        SecondaryDrawerItem item7 = new SecondaryDrawerItem().withIdentifier(7).withName("Offers").withIcon(R.drawable.tag);
        SecondaryDrawerItem item8 = new SecondaryDrawerItem().withIdentifier(8).withName(R.string.aboutapp).withIcon(R.drawable.credits);
        SecondaryDrawerItem item9 = new SecondaryDrawerItem().withIdentifier(9).withName(R.string.feedback).withIcon(R.drawable.feedback);
        SecondaryDrawerItem item10 = new SecondaryDrawerItem().withIdentifier(10).withName(R.string.helpcentre).withIcon(R.drawable.helpccenter);

        SecondaryDrawerItem item12 = new SecondaryDrawerItem().withIdentifier(12).withName("App Tour").withIcon(R.drawable.tour);
        SecondaryDrawerItem item13 = new SecondaryDrawerItem().withIdentifier(13).withName("Explore").withIcon(R.drawable.explore);


        //creating navbar and adding to the toolbar ------------------------------------------------
        result = new DrawerBuilder()
                .withActivity(this)
                .withToolbar(toolbar)
                .withHasStableIds(true)
                .withDrawerLayout(R.layout.crossfade_drawer)
                .withAccountHeader(headerResult)
                .withDrawerWidthDp(72)
                .withGenerateMiniDrawer(true)
                .withTranslucentStatusBar(true)
                .withActionBarDrawerToggleAnimated(true)
                .addDrawerItems(
                        item1, item2, item3, item4, item5, new DividerDrawerItem(), item7, item8, item9, item10,new DividerDrawerItem(),item12,item13
                )
                .withOnDrawerItemClickListener(new Drawer.OnDrawerItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onItemClick(View view, int position, IDrawerItem drawerItem) {

                        switch (position) {

                            case 1:
                                if (result != null && result.isDrawerOpen()) {
                                    result.closeDrawer();
                                }
                                break;
                            case 2:
                                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Profile.class));
                                break;
                            case 3:
                                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Wishlist.class));
                                break;
                            case 4:
                                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Cart.class));
                                break;
                            case 5:
                                session.logoutUser();
                                finish();
                                break;

                            case 7:
                                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, NotificationActivity.class));
                                break;

                            case 8:
                                new LibsBuilder()
                                        .withFields(R.string.class.getFields())
                                        .withActivityTitle(getString(R.string.about_activity_title))
                                        .withAboutIconShown(true)
                                        .withAboutAppName(getString(R.string.app_name))
                                        .withAboutVersionShown(true)
                                        .withLicenseShown(true)
                                        .withAboutSpecial1(getString(R.string.domain))
                                        .withAboutSpecial1Description(getString(R.string.website))
                                        .withAboutSpecial2(getString(R.string.licence))
                                        .withAboutSpecial2Description(getString(R.string.licencedesc))
                                        .withAboutSpecial3(getString(R.string.changelog))
                                        .withAboutSpecial3Description(getString(R.string.changes))
                                        .withShowLoadingProgress(true)
                                        .withAboutDescription(getString(R.string.about_activity_description))
                                        .withActivityStyle(Libs.ActivityStyle.LIGHT_DARK_TOOLBAR)
                                        .start(MainActivity.this);
                                break;
                            case 9:
                                new EasyFeedback.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                                        .withEmail("beingdevofficial@gmail.com")
                                        .withSystemInfo()
                                        .build()
                                        .start();
                                break;
                            case 10:
                                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, HelpCenter.class));
                                break;
                            case 12:
                                session.setFirstTimeLaunch(true);
                                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, WelcomeActivity.class));
                                finish();
                                break;
                            case 13:
                                if (result != null && result.isDrawerOpen()) {
                                    result.closeDrawer();
                                }
                                tapview();
                                break;
                            default:
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Default", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        }

                        return true;
                    }
                })
                .build();

        //Setting crossfader drawer------------------------------------------------------------

        crossfadeDrawerLayout = (CrossfadeDrawerLayout) result.getDrawerLayout();

        //define maxDrawerWidth
        crossfadeDrawerLayout.setMaxWidthPx(DrawerUIUtils.getOptimalDrawerWidth(this));

        //add second view (which is the miniDrawer)
        final MiniDrawer miniResult = result.getMiniDrawer();

        //build the view for the MiniDrawer
        View view = miniResult.build(this);

        //set the background of the MiniDrawer as this would be transparent
        view.setBackgroundColor(UIUtils.getThemeColorFromAttrOrRes(this, com.mikepenz.materialdrawer.R.attr.material_drawer_background, com.mikepenz.materialdrawer.R.color.material_drawer_background));

        //we do not have the MiniDrawer view during CrossfadeDrawerLayout creation so we will add it here
        crossfadeDrawerLayout.getSmallView().addView(view, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

        //define the crossfader to be used with the miniDrawer. This is required to be able to automatically toggle open / close
        miniResult.withCrossFader(new ICrossfader() {
            @Override
            public void crossfade() {
                boolean isFaded = isCrossfaded();
                crossfadeDrawerLayout.crossfade(400);

                //only close the drawer if we were already faded and want to close it now
                if (isFaded) {
                    result.getDrawerLayout().closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public boolean isCrossfaded() {
                return crossfadeDrawerLayout.isCrossfaded();
            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        sliderShow.stopAutoCycle();
        super.onStop();

    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (result != null && result.isDrawerOpen()) {
            result.closeDrawer();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    public void viewProfile(View view) {
        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Profile.class));
    }

    public void viewCart(View view) {
        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Cart.class));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {

        //check Internet Connection
        new CheckInternetConnection(this).checkConnection();
        sliderShow.startAutoCycle();
        super.onResume();
    }

    public void Notifications(View view) {
        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, NotificationActivity.class));
    }

    public void cardsActivity(View view) {
        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Cards.class));
    }

    public void tshirtActivity(View view) {
        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Tshirts.class));
    }


    public void bagsActivity(View view) {

        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Bags.class));
    }

    public void stationaryAcitivity(View view) {

        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Stationary.class));
    }

    public void calendarsActivity(View view) {

        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Calendars.class));
    }

    public void keychainsActivity(View view) {

        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Keychains.class));
    }
}
```

Comment: add your SplashActivity's xml layout codes

Answer (score 0):

Just add in your app(the one which says Module:app) level build.gradle

```
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
```

in you log data, we can clearly see

```
     "Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Binary 
     XML file line #2: Error inflating class 
     androidx.constraintlayout.ConstraintLayout"
```

after implementing the constraint-layout library, just sync and clean your project.